# count unique value in whole table [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+-------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------+
|    id |             A_id |                  B_id |              C_id | age  |
+-------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------+
|    44 |               22 |                    22 |                22 |   35 |
|    47 |                6 |                  NULL |                 6 |   33 |
|    48 |                4 |                  NULL |                 4 |   32 |
|    52 |               23 |                  NULL |                23 |   37 |
|    54 |                9 |                     9 |              NULL |   37 |
|    55 |             NULL |                     8 |              NULL |   29 |
|    60 |                8 |                  NULL |                 8 |   37 |
|    62 |                8 |                  NULL |                 8 |   35 |
|    65 |               11 |                  NULL |                11 |   46 |
|    69 |                9 |                  NULL |                 9 |   52 |
+-------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------+
```

I'd like to count the total number of rows with certain values, that is:

```
_id - count(id)
22 - 1
6 - 1
4 - 1
23 - 1
9 - 2
8 - 3
11 - 1
```

How would I write a query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that at least one of the values in each row is not NULL (can be tweaked a bit further to deal with it as well, but I think you wouldn't have any records like this).

It is not very pretty, but should work:

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST(IFNULL(A_id, 0), IFNULL(B_id, 0), IFNULL(C_id, 0)), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM table 
GROUP BY GREATEST(IFNULL(A_id, 0), IFNULL(B_id, 0), IFNULL(C_id, 0))
```

Same thing in a bit more compact way:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(A_id, IFNULL(B_id, C_id)),
    COUNT(*)
FROM table 
GROUP BY IFNULL(A_id, IFNULL(B_id, C_id))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work ;( when in grouped column NULL is present, I've modified original table, check it please. Thanks.

Comment: In that case we will get in result 8-2, but it's not true, because 8 meets 3 time in whole table, do you see difference ?

Comment: @user1016265 There are two 8's in your table, not three.

Comment: OK, so, what do you actually want to count? My answer is counting occurrences of numbers in column A_id. If you want to count all of the numbers, there are three 22's but in your output it is shown as 1. Clarify your question.

Comment: i guess its total number of rows with the number in either column A_id, B_id, C_id

Comment: @plainjane yes this is what I want

Comment: i mean there are three rows with number 8 in either column A_id, B_id, C_id

Comment: @plainjane exactly! I just don't know, how to explain it in proper English, this is why I've used example of expected result.

Comment: @sashkello Thank you very much this is exactly what I need, I did shorter a bit with help alias ;) Thanks a lot! P.S. Now I'm going to test it on bigger amount of data

Comment: @sashkello perfect answer

Comment: @sashkello I had the same idea before I post question here, but I did not know anything about ifnull() and greatest(), these function are brilliant ;) I had an idea to make concat and somehow deal with integer and null. So thank you very much. With your help now I know few more useful MySQL functions ;)

Comment: @user1016265 Welcome, mate. Takes time to get to know all of those keywords, but you'll get there :)